# How to remove dead ubuntu dash application links?

Tags: unity-dash, .desktop

I attempted to test out Lutrix on ubuntu 17.10 with League of Legends. Everything worked fine and well.

After testing it out I no longer needed Lutrix, Wine, or the game so I purged both Lutrix and Wine and deleted the Wine directory along with its contents.

However I can still see the League of Legends and Uninstall League of Legends launcher in Dash.

I have searched in `/usr/share/application` and in `/usr/local/share/applications` but can't find anything. I also performed a full system search and came up with no *.desktop files that fit the description.

Is there any other way that Ubuntu registers launchers in Dash that I am missing?